# Visual Studio vs VBA in Word

Tags: vba, visual-studio, ms-word

Is it benificial to download Visual Studio Community  for VBA programming?

Or is it better just to run Visual Basics out of a word document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBA and VB aren't the same thing.

VBA is **V**isual **B**asic for **A**pplications and is derived from VB. VBA is encapsulated within Microsoft Office and is primarily event driven, whereas Visual Basic is a fully fledged OOP language that's used within the Visual Studio IDE.

You can create VSTO add-ins for office using VB within Visual Studio - but unless you have a specific reason to I would stick with using VBA as the language has been developed with Office automation in mind, and so the objects and the built in IDE providing features such as IntelliSense are already configured to help you achieve what you need

Ultimate point here is that there's no point re-inventing the wheel. Stick with VBA.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation